# Clock Offset CDH 5.10 (with Kudu in particular)

Tags: clock, cloudera-cdh

Prior to the CDH 5.10 release all aspects seem to work OK with the Cloudera VMs that I installed. With CDH 5.10 all components are at various times suffering clock-offset issues. I am a bit surprised. Restarting and issuing clock reset commands are rather annoying. Any pointers out there? Reading documentation does not seem to help in that all aspects do not remedy what is going on once and for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/kudu-service-are-getting-down-frequently/td-p/55644

So as to prove the point that others have experienced this as well. Low view count tells me something as well.

Comment: CDH 5.12 seems fine now, check the set UTC Time flag.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't recommend Toshiba as VM platform, too many blue screens. Cannot recover sometime the vmdk.

2) Install software yourself, less issues.

3) It seems to be random, after restarting ntp, restarting stale configurations, and being patient, sometimes it is stable until some safe mode issue turns up.

All in all quite disappointing when compared to prior releases of CDH.

Comment: Happening with old CDH5.4 now. Think an issue with Toshiba?